# ClassLoader: how to load class from another project

Tags: java, class

I want to access a class from another project using ClassLoader. How can I specify the path to that class and get that class file?

I want to be able to do this through code as I will be loading many different class files through my application and the path for the different classes will be constantly changing.

I am using a CustomClassLoader which is loading class files but only if they are in the project and not in another project

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.AccessControlContext;
import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction;

public class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

String repoLocation = "C:/TempBINfolder/bin/";

public CustomClassLoader() {
}

public CustomClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
    super(parent);
}

@Override
protected Class<?> findClass(final String name)
        throws ClassNotFoundException {

    AccessControlContext acc = AccessController.getContext();

    try {
        return (Class) AccessController.doPrivileged(
                new PrivilegedExceptionAction() {

                    public Object run() throws ClassNotFoundException {

                        FileInputStream fi = null;
                        try {

                            String path = name.replace('.', '/');
                            fi = new FileInputStream(repoLocation + path
                                    + ".class");
                            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // a big chunk
                            int read;
                            while ((read = fi.read(buffer)) > 0)
                                baos.write(buffer, 0, read);
                            byte[] classBytes= baos.toByteArray();

                            return defineClass(name, classBytes, 0,
                                    classBytes.length);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
                        }
                    }
                }, acc);
    } catch (java.security.PrivilegedActionException pae) {
        return super.findClass(name);
    }
}
}
```

Calling the class

```
for (Class singleClass : listOfClasses) {
            try {

                ClassLoader classLoader = new CustomClassLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
                Class stringClass = null;
                try {
                    stringClass = classLoader.loadClass(singleClass.getName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(CompilerForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                try {
                    stringClass.newInstance();
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(CompilerForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(CompilerForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }


                Class cls = Class.forName(stringClass.getName());
```

If i try to do `Class cls = Class.forName(stringClass.getPackage()+"."+stringClass.getName());` the package is `null`

**EDIT: The following worked for me**

```
URL classUrl;
classUrl = new URL("file:///"+ccl.getRepoLocation());    //This is location of .class file
URL[] classUrls = {classUrl};
URLClassLoader ucl = new URLClassLoader(classUrls);
Class cls = ucl.loadClass(stringClass.getName());    // Current .class files name
```

Comment: How is this being used? You're not mentioning how these projects are being bundled, or why you're using a custom ClassLoader in the first place. The typical case would be to at least jar up each project and put the dependency jar on the classpath for the other jar (in which case you should be able to get it using `parent.getResourceAsStream("...")`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [URLClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) to do that for you.

Answer (score 2):

That code looks good (I've myself did something similar a long time ago). Altough there's a little bug:

If you do

```
byte[] classBytes = new byte[fi.available()];
fi.read(classBytes);
```

You are only reading so many bytes as *bytes available with no blocking* are. It is, you're not reading the whole file. In fact, read method doesn't assure the complete byte buffer will be read.

Try to do:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // a big chunk
int read;
while ((read = fi.read(buffer)) > 0)
   baos.write(buffer, 0, read);
byte[] bytesClass = baos.toByteArray();
```

or use [Streams.copy](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/util/Streams.html) from Apache. It's a convenience method to do the same.

**Package definition**

ClassLoader has a `definePackage` method. I'd bet that you should call that method for every new package you need. Otherwise ClassLoader has no way to define a package but from the full classname and it seems it's not enough.

So code get to this:

```
// being package the name of the package for the new class
// being definedPackages a Set<String> member of the classloader

if (!this.definedPackages.contains(package)) {
   definePackage(package,"","","","","","",null);
   this.definedPackages.add(package);
}
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // a big chunk
int read;
while ((read = fi.read(buffer)) > 0)
   baos.write(buffer, 0, read);
byte[] bytesClass = baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Not at all. But then, the problem is not loading the class but retrieving the correspondent Package right? (I misunderstood that)

Comment: ya, i can get the class alright but it is just to get the package that the class is in is the problem!

Comment: Well, added definePackage to my post... seems it's relevant :)

Comment: but i am calling that in my CustomClassLoader (above) so that should return the class path so should it?

Comment: You must call definePackage (at least if you didn't defined the package before) and then call defineClass. By example: `findClass("a.b.C")` is invoked. Then you call `definePackage("a.b", ...)` and then `defineClass(...)`. So the returned Class object will be attached to a new Package object corresponding to the definePackage invocation just made. Remember to not call definePackage twice for the same package.

Comment: I was looking into this and it is possible to do it this way and probably more efficient if i did it this way but was unable to do this myself so i decided to use `URLClassLoader`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the Above Code which Helped me .

SUB : calling same class available in two different locations

I have a class say Abc in classpath jar file and dynamically I generate the same class Abc in local directory with some code changes.

I need to create instance and use the class Abc in local directory ,
Below is the Working Code ,

class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

```
String repoLocation = "./";
//C:/TempBINfolder/bin/
 CustomClassLoader() {
}

 CustomClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
    super(parent);
}

@Override
protected Class<?> findClass(final String name)   throws ClassNotFoundException {

    AccessControlContext acc = AccessController.getContext();

    try {
        return (Class) AccessController.doPrivileged(
                new PrivilegedExceptionAction() {

                    public Object run() throws ClassNotFoundException {

                        FileInputStream fi = null;
                        try {

                            String path = name.replace('.', '/');
                            fi = new FileInputStream(repoLocation + path+ ".class");
                            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // a big chunk
                            int read;
                            while ((read = fi.read(buffer)) > 0)
                                baos.write(buffer, 0, read);
                            byte[] classBytes= baos.toByteArray();

                            return defineClass(name, classBytes, 0,
                                    classBytes.length);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            throw new ClassNotFoundException(name);
                        }
                    }
                }, acc);
    } catch (java.security.PrivilegedActionException pae) {
        return super.findClass(name);
    }
}
}
```

calling the CustomClassLoader  class,

```
    ClassLoader classLoader = new CustomClassLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
    Class stringClass = (new CustomClassLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader())).findClass(packageName+"."+javaFileName);
    Object  t = (Object) stringClass.newInstance();
```

Thanks,
Murwath